# Как сделать вынужденное ожидание конца трансформации?

Tags: javascript, css, transition

Есть вот такой слайдер, и прописана трансформация для него, если пользователь будет кликать очень быстро, то слайдер не будет успевать пролистывать "кадр" полностью и может остановится на середине, например.
Как избежать такого эффекта?
P.S. чем проще вариант, тем лучше)

```js
var strip = document.getElementById('filmstrip');
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var adv = document.querySelectorAll('.filmstrip>img');
var count = adv.length;
var next= document.getElementById('next');
var back= document.getElementById('back');
//ниже действие вперед
next.onclick = move;
function move() {
    var current=parseInt(getComputedStyle(strip).left);
    var imgWidth = adv[0].clientWidth;
    if(current<=-imgWidth*(count-4)){
        next.style.display="none";
    }
    if (current<=-imgWidth*(count-3)){
    }else{
    strip.style.left=current-imgWidth+('px');
    back.style.display="block";
    }
}
//ниже действие назад
back.onclick = remove;
function remove(){
    var current=parseInt(getComputedStyle(strip).left);
    var imgWidth = adv[0].clientWidth;
    if(current>=-imgWidth*(1)){
        back.style.display="none";
    }
    if (current>=0){
    }else{
    strip.style.left=current+imgWidth+('px');
    next.style.display="block";
    }
}
```

```css
.slider{
 overflow: hidden;
 width:90%;
 height:auto;
}
.filmstrip{
 position: relative;
 height:100px;
 left:0;
 white-space: nowrap; 
 transition: left 1s;
}
.filmstrip img{
 width:33.34%;
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider">

      <div class="filmstrip" id="filmstrip">
      <img style="background:black">
      <img style="background:red">
      <img style="background:blue">
      <img style="background:pink">
      <img style="background:green">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="next">вперед</div>
<div id="back">назад</div>
```

Comment: снять обработчик клика, после клика - дождаться окончания трансформации (transitionend) и повесить обработчик клика снова. Код не напишу - с телефона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var strip = document.getElementById('filmstrip');
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var adv = document.querySelectorAll('.filmstrip>img');
var count = adv.length;
var next= document.getElementById('next');
var back= document.getElementById('back');
//ниже действие вперед
next.addEventListener("click", move)
function move() {
 next.removeEventListener("click", move)
 back.removeEventListener("click", remove)
    var current=parseInt(getComputedStyle(strip).left);
    var imgWidth = adv[0].clientWidth;
    if(current<=-imgWidth*(count-4)){
        next.style.display="none";
    }
    if (current<=-imgWidth*(count-3)){
    }else{
    strip.style.left=current-imgWidth+('px');
    back.style.display="block";
    }
}
//ниже действие назад
back.addEventListener("click", remove)
function remove(){
 next.removeEventListener("click", move)
 back.removeEventListener("click", remove)
    var current=parseInt(getComputedStyle(strip).left);
    var imgWidth = adv[0].clientWidth;
    if(current>=-imgWidth*(1)){
        back.style.display="none";
    }
    if (current>=0){
    }else{
    strip.style.left=current+imgWidth+('px');
    next.style.display="block";
    }
}

strip.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
next.addEventListener("click", move)
back.addEventListener("click", remove)
})
```

```css
.slider{
 overflow: hidden;
 width:90%;
 height:auto;
}
.filmstrip{
 position: relative;
 height:100px;
 left:0;
 white-space: nowrap; 
 transition: left 1s;
}
.filmstrip img{
 width:33.34%;
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider">

      <div class="filmstrip" id="filmstrip">
      <img style="background:black">
      <img style="background:red">
      <img style="background:blue">
      <img style="background:pink">
      <img style="background:green">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="next">вперед</div>
<div id="back">назад</div>
```